# jQuery Isotope Masonry display content in clicked elements

Tags: jquery, click, jquery-animate, jquery-isotope

In David DeSandro's list of interesting Isotope implementations, there's one here http://www.wonderfulwebsolutions.net/ revealing additional content once an element is clicked (images, text, link, etc.). Although as newcomer to jQuery, I seem to have understood the very basic basics of this fantastic plugin - simple test here http://www.16percent.de/siehmaleineran.html I don't understand how to reveal content in each upsized element, once it has been clicked. I'm not after even more tricky stuff as the automatic slideshows running in the elements of that example; category filtering and sorting is also not important at all right now.

Does anyone know how this should be done the correct way? From another post I gleaned that first each element must be upsized for Isotope to work out the layout before else can happen.

Thank you very much in advance for any kind of insight.

Comment: If you want to answer your question, you should actually post an answer, not [edit the question](http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/310441).

Answer (score 0):

Answer to my own question is [here](http://www.16percent.de/) where it all works as expected.